# QTcpServer::write() - не отправляются пакеты

Tags: c++, qt, tcp, tcp-ip, qtcpsocket

Есть следующий код маленького сервачка:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QTcpServer>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTextStream cout(stdout);

    QTcpServer server;
    if(server.listen(QHostAddress::Any, 1122)){
        qDebug() << "Listenning....";
    }

    server.waitForNewConnection(10000);

    qDebug() << server.hasPendingConnections();
    QTcpSocket *socket = server.nextPendingConnection();
    socket->waitForReadyRead(5000);
    qDebug() << socket;
    qDebug() << socket->readAll();

    QString data = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n%1";
    socket->write(data.arg("message accepted").toLatin1());
    socket->flush();
    //socket->disconnectFromHost();

    return a.exec();
}
```

В браузере вбиваем адрес localhost:1122, тыцаем Enter и ждем. Сервер отображает данные которые пришли, и пытается ответить браузеру. Но ответ в браузере появляется только тогда, когда прописана строчка `//socket->disconnectFromHost();` Если строку не прописывать, то ответ не приходит. Что это может быть?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте воспользоваться [готовым решение](http://stefanfrings.de/qtwebapp/index-en.html).
Как я понимаю, не получится просто отправить строку в сокет, что бы браузер все понял. Нужно соблюсти кодировку (UTF-8), сжать данные (zlib, gzip), заполнить шапку HTTP/REST ответа.

Comment: Спасибо, за полезную ссылку. На данный момент я нашел, как мне кажется, ответ и немного разобрался.